# How can I write a unit test for a react component that calls reduxjs's mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I'm trying to write unit tests for a container component called `AsyncApp` but I get the following error "`mapStateToProps` must return an object. Instead received undefined."

This is my set-up.

**Root.js**

```
import configureStore from '../configureStore';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import AsyncApp from './AsyncApp';

const store = configureStore();

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AsyncApp />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  thunkMiddleware
  //loggerMiddleware
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState);
}
```

**AsyncApp.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { foo } from '../actions';
import FooComponent from '../components/FooComponent';

class AsyncApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onFoo= this.onFoo.bind(this);
    this.state = {}; // <--- adding this doesn't fix the issue
  }

  onFoo(count) {
    this.props.dispatch(foo(count));
  }

  render () {
    const {total} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <FooComponent onFoo={this.onFoo} total={total}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AsyncApp);
```

I'm passing `store` directly to `AsyncApp` in my test to avoid getting the following Runtime Error : `Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(AsyncApp)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(AsyncApp)".`

The test isn't complete yet because I can't get past the `mapStateToProps` error message.

**AsyncApp-test.js**

```
jest.dontMock('../../containers/AsyncApp');
jest.dontMock('redux');
jest.dontMock('react-redux');
jest.dontMock('redux-thunk');
jest.dontMock('../../configureStore');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
const configureStore = require( '../../configureStore');
const AsyncApp = require('../../containers/AsyncApp');

const store = configureStore();

//const asyncApp = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  //<AsyncApp store={store} />
//);

const shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
shallowRenderer.render(<AsyncApp store={store}/>);
```

I want to eventually test that `AsyncApp` contains a `FooComponent`, and that a `foo` action is dispatched when `onFoo` is called.

Is what I am trying to do achievable? Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The suggestion I've seen in a few places is to test the non-connected component, as opposed to the connected version.  So, verify that when you pass in specific props to your component you get the expected rendered output, and verify that when you pass in a state with a certain shape your `mapStateToProps()` returns the expected pieces.  Then you can expect that they should both work correctly when put together.

Comment: The Redux docs explicitly suggest this, in http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html .  There's also some relevant examples in other articles, like [Simple React/Redux Testing](https://medium.com/@caljrimmer/simple-react-redux-testing-cd579d4c2103#.i17zkdyo3) and [Unit Testing a Redux App](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/redux-unit-test-mocha-mocking)

Comment: Thanks, the redux docs really are clear on the issue. Should have seen that myself.

Comment: You may end up in the situation where you are testing the non-connected component...but in a reasonably complicated app, a -children- of that non-connected component could be connected. So it's not always that simple (unless only your top level components are connected).

Haven't found a good solution for that yet aside mocking imports.

Comment: @shados did you try something like this? `expect(result.type).to.equal(ConnectedChildComponent)` where `ConnectedChildComponent` is the imported, connected component - be aware that you're not checking for a string or a `<Element/>` but on the exported `connect(...)(YourComponent)` element.

Comment: @shados were you able to find a way to properly test connected components with nested connected component ?